# Will an Xcode project with Background Fetch turned on still work on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c

I just want to make sure that if i turn background fetch mode that my app will still be compatible with iOS 6.  I realize the background fetch portion of the app will not work in iOS 6.  I just want to make sure the rest of my application will continue to work once I turn this on in the project.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it should. As long as you don't call iOS 7 or 8 APIs without checking for their existence first, you should be fine. But really you should test in the simulator and on a device before shipping anyway.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I did fully test it on an iOS 6 device and I am wrapping iOS 7+ calls in version checks.  I just didn't want to end up in a situation where the apple app store set the minimum iOS version supported to iOS 7.0 because I had turned this on.  We need to continue to support iOS 6.

Comment: You should be fine. We still ship some apps for iOS 5, although it's getting harder and harder to work with both old and new APIs, especially for rotation and view layout and sizing.

Comment: Thanks for the help Eric.  Good to know this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like you can turn on background fetch support in the Xcode IDE and it will still work with iOS 6 provided you wrap newer api calls in OS version checks.